# TeamCity how to clone a full repository instead of a BARE one?

Tags: git, teamcity

We are using TeamCity 8 Professional 8.0.2 build 27482, we need to run some commands on git that are unsupported on a BARE repository. Is there a way to clone it as a regular one?

Comment: Are you sure it clones a bare one? I am asking, because I wonder how TeamCity is supposed to build your program if it doesn't have its source code...

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the command line, then a simple way to clone a non-bare repository is:

```
git clone repository-url-or-path
```

Non-bare repositories are the default for the `git clone` command.